# how to iterate and modify key-value pair inside map in Elixir. Sample code is below. I need to remove c: from everywhere

Tags: dictionary, elixir

** below is sample map which has c: in start of some keys and i want same map which do not have anywhere in keys **

```
map = %{
  "soap:Body" => {"c:replyMessage",
   %{
     "c:ccCaptureReply" => %{
       "c:amount" => "100.00",
       "c:reasonCode" => "100",
       "c:reconciliationID" => "2",
       "c:requestDateTime" => "2019-07-10T16:57:49Z"
     },
     "c:decision" => "ACCEPT",
     "c:merchantReferenceCode" => "1255",
     "c:purchaseTotals" => {"c:currency", "US"},
     "c:reasonCode" => "100",
     "c:requestID" => "2",
     "c:requestToken" => "FkKZy21",
     "xmlns:c" => "urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.165"
   }},
  "soap:Header" => {"wsse:Security",
   %{
     "wsu:Timestamp" => %{
       "wsu:Created" => "2019-07-10T16:57:49.246Z",
       "wsu:Id" => "Timestamp-90787002",
       "xmlns:wsu" => "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
     },
     "xmlns:wsse" => "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
   }},
  "xmlns:soap" => "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us. After you make a good attempt at doing this yourself and if you still have problems, you can update your question with details of the specific problem and what you have tried to solve it, and include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we are able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the deep traversal was supported by [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) core, you have tuples as values and tuples are not iteratable.

The only way would be to write the recursive solution based on pattern-matching.

```rb
defmodule Sanitizer do
  def yo(%{} = map) do
    map
    |> Enum.map(fn
      {<<"c:", rest::binary>>, v} -> {rest, yo(v)}
      {k, v} -> {k, yo(v)}
    end)
    |> Map.new()
  end
  def yo({<<"c:", rest::binary>>, v}), do: {rest, yo(v)}
  def yo({k, v}), do: {k, yo(v)}
  def yo(any), do: any
end

Sanitizer.yo(map)
#⇒ sanitized result
```

FWIW, there is [`Iteraptor`](https://hexdocs.pm/iteraptor/intro.html#content) library written by me back in times when I thought that having *leftpad*-like libraries for everything is good enough. It could deal with the input if it had no tuples (which simply are not traversable by any mean.)

Comment: Amazing I did not though I will get a reply so quickly. Thank @Aleksei for help

Comment: @AshishSharma you can also match with `{"c:" <> rest, v} -> …`